# Regarding Multi Site Wordpress on AWS

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, multisite

I am trying to setup wordpress multisite on an amazon AWS instance. These are the steps i followed based on the tutorial provided by wordpress (http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

1. Right now i don't have a domain name. Running over an IP address. So created a host on my local computer to access the site. The subdirectory options remains disabled without it.
2. Added the following in wp-config to enable multisite>

   /* Multisite */
   define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
3. Enabled multi site by choosing Subdirectory option (not subdomain)
4. Updated the wp-config with following by copying from wordpress setting provided during the installation.

   define('MULTISITE', true);
   define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
   define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'acoolsite.com');
   define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
   define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
   define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
5. Added .htaccess (didn't had it before. Just created a file .htaccess and put the following. Any additional steps needed? )

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*.php)$ $2 [L]
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
6. Server restarted. Logged out and login
7. Navigated to Network admin and created a site with name, description and an existing email.
8. Got the successful message.
9. If i try to access the site i get the following:
   [image]

What am i doing wrong here? The 1st site works perfectly. Is there any folder permission i can cross check? Also if a multi site is created will it create a folder in my wordpress directory? Currently no folder is created. How do i debug? Please help.

PS: Posted in webmaster forum first. Now moved to stackoverflow.

Comment: anyone guys? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Allow Overriding, for security purpose, Bitnami has move .htaccess file and merged with `/opt/bitnami/apps/samknives/conf/httpd-app.conf`.

This is file, `“AllowOverride”` is set to `“none”`, go ahead and change it to `“All”`.

[image]

**Referance: ** http://ahmedkhateeb.com/point-domain-to-sub-directory-in-apache-bitnami-virtual-hosts/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I recommend you is to use the official Bitnami documentation instead of any other tutorials when customizing a Bitnami Stack:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/

The Bitnami WP Multiste includes by default:

```
 define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php` WordPress configuration file.

You don't need to create any .htaccess files anywhere. All the htaccess information is collected and merged at `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htacces.conf` in the Bitnami WP Stack. This file is included in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/http-app.conf` configuration file. If you want to change any htaccess configuration, please edit the merged file.

The Bitnami Wordpress MultiSite is intended for the next scenarios:

- SCENARIO 1: You want multiple websites/blogs at subdomains of your primary domain eg. your primary domain is our-planets.com and you have separate websites/blogs at mercury.our-planets.com, mars.our-planets.com and earth.our-planets.com.
- SCENARIO 2: You want multiple websites/blogs at different domains eg. a website at our-planets.com and another at space-is-awesome.com.
- SCENARIO 3: You want a combination of the two previous scenarios eg. a primary domain at our-planets.com with separate blogs for Earth and Mars at earth.our-planets.com and mars.our-planets.com, another blog at space-is-awesome.com, and yet another blog at photos.space-is-awesome.com.

If you want to have different WP Sites using different subpath (not subdomains). I recommend you to follow the next guide:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/#how-to-install-several-wordpress-modules-on-the-same-stack

Basically, you can launch a Bitnami WordPress Stack (not the Multisite one) log in your server via SSH, download the Bitnami WordPress module (you can download it from https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/modules#wordpress) and install as many times as you desire the WP module with the BLOG_NAME you want.

```
chmod a+x bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-linux-x64-installer.run
./bitnami-wordpress-VERSION-module-linux-x64-installer.run --wordpress_instance_name NEW_BLOG_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your permalinks aren't working. Try this:

1. Go to /etc/httpd/conf and edit httpd.conf

   ```
   <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Change also AllowOverride if it is set to None.

   ```
   # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
   # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
   #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
   #
   AllowOverride All
   ```
3. Then restart Apache

   ```
   sudo service httpd restart
   ```